# Connection to MySQL on server via ODBC

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc

I'm writing a desktop application (in Delphi). I would like to connect to MySQL database on a server. Up till now I tested my application using MySQL installed on my local computer. I used ODBC connector and all tests went successfully. Problems have started when I tried to connect database on server via ODBC. I'm getting connection failed message all the time and I cannot do anything.

Please tell me, how should I connect to this MySQL?

Comment: a number of ways to connect to MySQL including coding examples at last link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437285/how-to-connect-to-mysql-server-without-odbc  And since no one can read the error with your ees but you, no one but you can know what to do to fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, mysql listens for incoming connections on port 3306.  Use can use telnet to test if a networking problem or firewall is preventing you from connecting to the server that MySQL is running on, using the following command:

```
telnet fqdn.of.mysqlserver.com 3306
```

If successful, you should see that it connects, followed by some encrypted gibberish from MySQL.  If it doesn't connect, then the problem is a firewall, a networking problem, the MySQL server is unreachable, or something else blocking the connection.

Comment: Your answer partly helped me, now I see that problem is in a firewall because telnet doesn't connect.

Comment: OK.  If there is a firewall in front of the MySQL server, then you will need to create a policy in that firewall to allow incoming connections on port 3306 from the machine that your Delphi application is running on.

Comment: Once you get past this step (where you can connect successfully), then you will probably have to grant privileges on your MySQL database to allow your Delphi application to access the database.